Is there a simple way to get per-protocol (i.e. IPv4/IPv6) statistics from netstat?
After a change of ISP, I've recently gotten IPv6 access, so I thought I'd play around a little with netstat to see if it's possible to get some kind of high-level per-protocol statistics from macOS Sonoma to see how much of my traffic is actually over IPv6. My experience with the BSD tools is limited, and netstat is a beast of a tool. Does anyone have any tips or pointers as to whether it's possible, and if so, how to do it?

Just a little advice: This is a mediocre-to-bad question that is made a little more acceptable by a decent answer. Not that you should not ask a question like this, but that this sort of question, a "tips and pointers" sort of question, is clearly off topic on this site. When you want to ask this kind of question, I recommend that you find a forum where open discussion is the point. Sites like SuperUser and its various sister sites require specific and practical questions that can be answered authoritatively by single answers. I hope you can see and understand the difference.

@music2myear - The mediocre answer was generated by a LLM.
